# Reducing execution time of PostgreSQL stored function

Tags: database, postgresql, function, stored-procedures

So in Postgres I created a function that creates a table vehicletracks_tracks and fills in with information calculated from original table. Original table includes the following atributes: `id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT, session character varying(32), client_id character varying(32) NOT NULL, vehicle_type smallint NOT NULL, geolocation geography(Geometry,4326) NOT NULL and "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL.`

In the function I calculate tracks and borders between them by observing time and velocity between two consecutive rows in original table. A fter creating tracks I calculate distance and duration of every track.

The function takes around 6 minutes and 30 seconds and then the output table is created and filled with rows. The original table has around 5 million rows. When you look at the procedure is there any possibility to reduce its execution time?

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vehicletracks()
      RETURNS void AS
      $BODY$
          DECLARE
            vrstica1 RECORD;
            vrstica2 RECORD;
            track_number INT;
          BEGIN
        SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehicletracks_tracks;
        CREATE TABLE vehicletracks_tracks (
          session character varying(32),
          client_id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
          vehicle_type smallint NOT NULL,
          track_number SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
          track_distance DOUBLE PRECISION,
          track_duration INTERVAL,
          track_start TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
          track_stop TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
        );

        DROP VIEW IF EXISTS group_by_client_session_vehicle;
        CREATE VIEW group_by_client_session_vehicle AS
        SELECT DISTINCT client_id, session, vehicle_type
        FROM roaduserspositions
        GROUP BY client_id, session, vehicle_type
        ORDER BY session, client_id, vehicle_type;

        FOR vrstica1 IN (SELECT * FROM group_by_client_session_vehicle)
          LOOP
            DROP VIEW IF EXISTS velocity_difference_view;
                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS difference_table;
                CREATE TABLE difference_table AS
                SELECT id, session, client_id, vehicle_type, geolocation, timestamp, time_difference, distance_difference
                FROM (SELECT t.*, t.timestamp - LAG(t.timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY t.session, t.client_id, t.vehicle_type, t.timestamp ASC) AS time_difference,
              ST_Distance(geolocation, LAG(geolocation) OVER (ORDER BY t.session, t.client_id, t.vehicle_type, t.timestamp ASC)) AS distance_difference
                      FROM (SELECT * 
                            FROM timonwww_roaduserspositions
                            WHERE client_id = vrstica1.client_id AND session = vrstica1.session AND vehicle_type = vrstica1.vehicle_type) AS t) AS tab
                ORDER BY session, client_id, vehicle_type, timestamp;

            CREATE VIEW velocity_difference_view AS (
            SELECT *, distance_difference / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time_difference) AS velocity
            FROM difference_table
            WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time_difference) > 0
            UNION 
            SELECT *, 0 AS velocity
            FROM difference_table
            WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time_difference) = 0
            ORDER BY session, client_id, vehicle_type, timestamp);

            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_time_difference;
            CREATE TABLE new_time_difference ( 
                track_id INTEGER,
                LIKE velocity_difference_view INCLUDING ALL);

            track_number := 1;
            INSERT INTO new_time_difference(track_id, id, session, client_id, vehicle_type, geolocation, timestamp, time_difference)
                SELECT
                CASE
              WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time_difference) < 300 AND velocity < 121 THEN track_number
              ELSE track_number + 1
            END AS track_id, id, session, client_id, vehicle_type, geolocation, timestamp, time_difference
            FROM velocity_difference_view OFFSET 1;

            track_number := 1;
                FOR vrstica2 IN (SELECT * FROM velocity_difference_view OFFSET 1)
              LOOP
                IF EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM vrstica2.time_difference) < 300 AND vrstica2.velocity < 121 THEN
                  INSERT INTO new_time_difference VALUES(track_number, vrstica2.id, vrstica2.session, vrstica2.client_id, vrstica2.vehicle_type, vrstica2.geolocation, vrstica2.timestamp, vrstica2.time_difference);
                ELSE
                  track_number := track_number + 1;
                END IF;
              END LOOP;

                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS geolocation_difference_table;
                CREATE TABLE geolocation_difference_table AS
                SELECT *
                FROM (SELECT *, ST_Distance(geolocation, LAG(geolocation) over (ORDER BY timestamp ASC)) as geolocation_difference
                      FROM new_time_difference
                      WHERE track_id IN (SELECT * FROM generate_series((SELECT MIN(new_time_difference.track_id) FROM new_time_difference), (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM new_time_difference)) num)) AS tab;

            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS track_distance_table;
            CREATE TABLE track_distance_table AS
            SELECT track_id, SUM(geolocation_difference) AS track_distance, SUM(time_difference) AS track_duration, MIN(timestamp) AS track_start, MAX(timestamp) AS track_stop
            FROM geolocation_difference_table
            GROUP BY track_id
            ORDER BY track_id ASC;  

            INSERT INTO vehicletracks_tracks(session, client_id, vehicle_type, track_distance, track_duration, track_start, track_stop) 
            SELECT vrstica1.session, vrstica1.client_id, vrstica1.vehicle_type, track_distance, track_duration, track_start, track_stop
            FROM (SELECT * FROM track_distance_table WHERE track_distance > 0 AND track_distance IS NOT NULL) AS t;

          END LOOP;

          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehicletracks_binding;
          CREATE TABLE vehicletracks_binding AS
          SELECT id, track_id
          FROM geolocation_difference_table
          ORDER BY track_id ASC;

          DROP VIEW IF EXISTS group_by_client_session_vehicle;
          DROP VIEW IF EXISTS velocity_difference_view;
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS difference_table;
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_time_difference;
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS geolocation_difference_table;
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS track_distance_table;

          END;  
      $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
```

Comment: Use `auto_explain` or PLprofiler to figure out where the time is spent.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.